# Secure PUBNUB doesnt fire callback

Tags: javascript, security, pubnub

```
pubnub = PUBNUB.secure({
         subscribe_key : "#{config.subscribe_key}",
         publish_key   : "#{config.publish_key}",
         origin        : 'pubsub.pubnub.com',
         ssl           : true,
         cipher_key    : "#{config.publish_key}"
});

pubnub.subscribe({
        restore  : true,
        channel  : 'broadcast',
        callback : function(data) {
          debugger;
          new_message_notification(data);
        }
});
```

Callback is not working, but I see responses in NETWORK tab in browser.
Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Thats because you have not called

```
PUBNUB.init
```

So pubnub cannot initialize.

So..

```
pubnub = PUBNUB.init({

 subscribe_key : "#{config.subscribe_key}",
 publish_key   : "#{config.publish_key}",
 origin        : 'pubsub.pubnub.com',
 ssl           : true,
 cipher_key    : "#{config.publish_key}"

});
```

Should be more likley correct.

Comment: `secure` is supposed to incorporate `init` and provide additional settings (e.g. cipher_key)

Answer (score 0):

## PubNub Cryptography in JavaScript

> There is a new version of PubNub JavaScript: **[JavaScript API Reference for Realtime Apps](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/api-reference#init)**

Use the following code example to establish an AES 256 bit with SSL 2048 encryption.  You can find the live example here: http://pubnub.github.com/pubnub-api/crypto/index.html

```
<script src=https://pubnub.a.ssl.fastly.net/pubnub-3.3.min.js></script>
<script src=http://pubnub.github.com/pubnub-api/crypto/crypto.js></script>
<script src=http://pubnub.github.com/pubnub-api/crypto/encrypt-pubnub.js></script>
<script>(function(){
    var publish_key   = PUBNUB.$('pub').value;
    var subscribe_key = PUBNUB.$('sub').value;
    var channel       = PUBNUB.$('channel').value;
    var origin        = PUBNUB.$('origin').value;
    var message       = PUBNUB.$('message');
    var output        = PUBNUB.$('output');
    var cipher_key    = PUBNUB.$('cipher_key')
                              .value.split(/\s/).join('');

    var secure_pubnub = PUBNUB.secure({
        publish_key   : publish_key,
        subscribe_key : subscribe_key,
        origin        : origin,
        ssl           : true,
        cipher_key    : cipher_key
    });

    secure_pubnub.subscribe({
        channel  : channel,
        connect  : send_message,
        callback : alert
    });

    function send_message() {
        secure_pubnub.publish({
            channel : channel,
            message : message.value
        });
    }

    send_message();

})();</script>
```

Comment: `secure` is now deprecated and you can just use `init` or just `PUBNUB{...}` without `init` works the same. Get the latest PubNub JavaScript SDK here: http://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk